# Ajax Request form And show table without PartialView

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible send an AJAX request when a form is submit, then show a list below the form? If use razor `foreach` my page will be reloaded. I would use a PartialView to solve that problem.

Can I use AJAX to submit and return the list? If the AJAX request is successful, I could create the code bellow.

```js
for (int i = 0; i < data.lenght; i++) {
  $('#MyElement').append('tr' +
    '<td>' + data.Id + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + data.Name + '</td>' +
    +'</tr>');
}
```

I tried it, but without success. I would like to know if it is possible, or just PartialView.

Comment: You haven't shown your AJAX code. Also note that you have a syntax error in the last line, as you have two concatenation operators: `+ + '</tr>'`. Also you're missing the angle brackets around the opening `<tr>`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, change `lenght` to `length`. Check if `data` is properly fetched by using `console.log(data)` (check your browser console). if the data is printed in the console and you still can't loop and append the data to HTML DOM, then use this :

```
$.each(data,function(index, dataValue){
   $('#myElement').append('<tr>'+'<td>' + dataValue.Id + '</td>' + '<td>' + dataValue.Name + '</td>' + '</tr>'
   )
})
```

Comment: Error 500 is an internal error which means the error is from your backend

Comment: It was solved in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48630994/parse-json-list-via-c-in-jquery-ajax-success-callback/48631308#48631308 Thank you @Silverman42