# Parse JSON List (via C#) in jQuery AJAX Success Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using jQuery's AJAX methods to call a C# service to return a JSON serialized list.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SearchTicket(ViewModelTicket ticket) {

    var list = UnitOfTicket.Where(x =>x.TicketId == ticket.TicketId);

    return Json(new { list  }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I parse the response from within the success callback function and render it as HTML.

```js
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(Ticket),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (list) {
            var data = list;
            for (var i in data) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data[i]));
                $('#tbody-element').append(
                     '<tr>' +
                         '<td>' + data[i].TicketId + '</td>' +
                         '<td>' + data[i].Title + '</td>' +
                         '<td>' + data[i].PriorityId + '</tr>' +
                         '<td>' + data[i].OpenDateAndTime + '</tr>' +
                         '<td>' + data[i].SlaExpiration + '</td>' +
                     '</tr>'
                 );
             }
         },
         error: function () {
             alert("Error occured!!")
         }
     });
```

The response is displayed in an alert:

```
[{"TicketId":1,"OpenDateAndTime":"/Date(1517833557277)/","ClosedDateTime":null,"VersionId":140,"PriorityId":2,"CompanyId":0,"UserId":null,"Rate":null,"SlaExpiration":null,"TicketTypeId":1,"StatusId":1,"ProductId":1,"SubProductId":1,"TaskId":1,"Title":"Primeiro Chamado","Files":null}]
```

My problem is rendering an object with an undefinded value. For example: data[i].Title ...

I am following this post: [Parse returned C# list in AJAX success function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33508689/parse-returned-c-sharp-list-in-ajax-success-function)

Comment: Test if its undefined -`if (data[i]) { ... } else { ..}`

Comment: And you only want 5 properties of your objects so you should only be return those 5 properties, not all properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try `alert(JSON.stringify(data))` what do you see? Your code works as if `data` is an Array of objects, but it may actually be an Array full of nested Arrays.

If `alert(JSON.stringify(data[i]));` is showing you `[{"TicketId":...}]` it looks like `data[i]` is an Array containing a single object--in this case, `data[i].TicketId` is undefined but `data[i][0].TicketId` should have the value you want. If this is the case, using `data[i][0]` instead of `data[i]` across the board should help you out.

---

Note: I'd be careful about using `for (var i in data)`, though, since if `data` is an `Array` and you have any sort of data added to `Array.prototype` (e.g. a polyfilled Array method), then it will be included in this loop. It'd be safer to use:

```
for (var i in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: And the reason that happens is because OP is using `return Json(new { list  }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` when the correct code is just `return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify(Ticket),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (list) {
        for(var i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++) {
            $('#tbody-element').append(
                 '<tr>' +
                     '<td>' + list[i].TicketId + '</td>' +
                     '<td>' + list[i].Title + '</td>' +
                     '<td>' + list[i].PriorityId + '</tr>' +
                     '<td>' + list[i].OpenDateAndTime + '</tr>' +
                     '<td>' + list[i].SlaExpiration + '</td>' +
                 '</tr>'
             );
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error occured!!")
    }
});
```

Your response is already parsed which means your `list` variable is an array.